# How to make timer in activity, which can create TextView?

Tags: android, dynamic, timer, textview, scrollview

Is it possible to make some cycle timer (for example each 3 seconds), which control parameters in another class, and if is some condition true, then create TextView?

Some pseudo-code:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.function({

   if(dataFromAnotherLogicClass.isChanged() == true) {
      newText = createNewTextField;
      setText("new field...");
      insertInVectorArray(newText);
      scrollView.addView(newText);
   }

}, 3000);
```

Is it possible?
I tried this:

```
ScrollView content = (ScrollView)this.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);


        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(true) {
                  final TextView tempText = new TextView(I_DONT_KNOW_HOW_TO_SET_CONTEXT_HERE);
                  //android studio said tempText must be final :/
                  tempText.setText("Činnosť.."); //so this is not good
                  content.addView(tempText);

                  textViews.add(tempText);
                }
            }
        }, 3000, 3000);
```

Please help

Comment: is my updated answer work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes Its possible but you have add view on main thread 
    In Scroll view just take LinearLayout and next view add in LinearLayout not in scroll view

```
  LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

create and add textview Like this

```
 private void addNewView() {
     TextView myTxt = new TextView(this);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(105, 105);
     parms.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
     myTxt.setLayoutParams(parms);
     myTxt.setText("");
     view.addView(myTxt);
}
```

Updated-1

use timertask like this, It call recursively setTimer and when hit time then add your view

```
private void setTimer() {
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer = null;
    }
    if (mTimer == null) {
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        addNewView();
                        setTimer()
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

I hope its works for you

Comment: this is not exactly what i need.. i need it in timer cycle